# Why i need to resolve a response in promise

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, axios

I have a promise like below:

```
let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  axios.post("https://httpbin.org/post", params, header)
    .then(response => {
      resolve(Object.assign({}, response.data));
      // resolve("aaaa");
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(error => reject(error))
});
```

Why i need to resolve this promise with response data?

What happens if i replace `resolve(Object.assign({}, response.data));` line by `resolve("aaaa");` ?

Any one can help me? Thank you.

Comment: then ur `promise` will resolve with `"aaa"`. So `promise.then(res => console.log(res))` would give `"aaa"` instead of an object

Comment: [Promise - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: `axios.post` already returns a Promise. Wrapping that code in a `new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {})` is not only not required but also an anti pattern.

Comment: axios is using native javascript promise but maybe you are wrapping it into bluebird promises, for your requirements, only if the code is not written by you. else dont do so.

Comment: @AZ_ using `new Promise` is also an anti pattern if you want to convert it from one promise type to another. `BlueBirdPromise.resolve(retrunsNativePromise())` would be the correct way to do a conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Something that's worth mentioning is `axios.post()` already returns a `Promise` so you needn't wrap it in another promise.

This will work instead:

```
let promise = axios.post("https://httpbin.org/post", params, header)
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response);
    return Object.assign({}, response.data);
  });

// Later on...
promise.then(data => {
  console.log('Request successful:', data);
}, err => {
  console.log('Request failed:', err);
});
```

Constructing a new `Promise` object is only necessary when you aren't chaining off an existing promise, like in this example:

```
function delay(duration) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, duration));
}

delay(1000).then(() => {
  console.log('this code is delayed by 1s');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`resolve()` does exactly what the name says: It resolves the promise returning the value inside the function call.

So if you have a promise and it is resolving with `resolve('aaaaa')`, this means your promise will return a successful state with it's value being 'aaaaa'.

You could also reject the promise. This would mean the call you did failed at some point. Analog to `resolve()`, `reject()` accepts a parameter that should be returned by the promise.

Answer (score 0):

Promises have two arguments, `resolve` and `reject`, that are used to send a response back to the invoking code.
If your promise completed its code without errors, then you `resolve()` it, by sending back the response (it can be whatever you want) and if it fails instead, you `reject()` it, usually passing the error as parameter.

The parameter of the resolve function will be sent back to the invoking function, in the *then* callback, while the parameter of the reject function can be found in the *catch* callback.

For example

```
function myFunction(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try{
            /* Do some async calls here */
            resolve(result); //Result is what you will find in "then"
        }catch(e){
            reject(e);
        }
    });
}

myFunction().then((response) => {
    /* Your logic here*/
}).catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
}
```

You can think the `resolve` as a `return` in an asynchronous context, while the `reject` is similar to `throw`ing an exception that will be caught by the invoking code.

So `resolve(myVariable)` will return `myVariable` to the code that called the promise function, while `resolve('aaa')` will always return "aaa" to the invoking code.

Answer (score 0):

All it will do is call the success callback `resolve` with the argument `"aaaa"` instead of its original value.

Let's say you pass the callback function `console.log`. If the promise resolves, i.e. is successful, then the callback will be called with the passed argument (`console.log("aaaa")`)

If it doesn't resolve - if it's unsuccessful - then the `reject` callback will be called as per your `.catch()` statement.